# searchfield with redux with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application and a search functionality. But now I try to implement redux with the application. So if I load the application no errors. But if I just type something in the searchbox I get this error:

```
TypeError: searchfield.toLowerCase is not a function

//const { robots, searchfield } = this.state;
  44 | //const {searchField, onSearchChange} = props;
  45 | const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
> 46 |   return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
     | ^  47 | });
  48 | return !robots.length ?
  49 |   <h1>Loading</h1> :
```

So this is app.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchfield
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
  }
}

function App(props) {
  

  const [robots, robotState] = useState([]);
  const [searchfield, stateSearchField] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => { robotState(users) });   
  }, []);


  const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
  });
  return !robots.length ?
    <h1>Loading</h1> :
    (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={stateSearchField} />
        <Scroll>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Scroll>
      </div>
    );

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

reducer.js:

```
import { CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD } from './constants.js';


const initialState = {
    searchField: ''
}

export const searchRobots = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { searchField: action.payload });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

actions.js

```
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from './constants'

export const setSearchField = (text)=> ({
                type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
                payload: text

});
```

searchbox.js

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox = ({ searchfield, searchChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className='pa2'>
      <input
        className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        type='search'
        placeholder='search robots'
        onChange={searchChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

my question: what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stateSearchField` is the function responsible to record/updating the value of `searchfield` variable of the `useState` hook. The cause of this issue is that you aren't updating the values properly as and when the input is given/updated. The `SearchBox` component's `searchChange` props point to `stateSearchField` which is further triggered when the input value is changed. But the problem here is that, the input value is not passed when updating the state, hence it is setting the `searchfield` value to `undefined`, and in the `filter` function you are trying to invoke the method `toLowerCase()` on `searchfield` which is `undefined`. The fix is pretty simple, just pass the input value whenever the input is changed. This can be done in the `SearchBox` component.

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox = ({ searchfield, searchChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className='pa2'>
      <input
        className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        type='search'
        placeholder='search robots'
        onChange={e=>searchChange(e.target.value)} //accept the event argument and pass the extracted value from the input to searchChange prop function.
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Or use a handler function to accomplish the same,

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBox = ({ searchfield, searchChange }) => {
  function updateInput(e){
    searchChange(e.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className='pa2'>
      <input
        className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        type='search'
        placeholder='search robots'
        onChange={updateInput}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Comment: Thank you!! But maybe I still don't get it. But I thought this: const [searchfield, stateSearchField] = useState(''); you don't need anymore in app.js. Because now the state is replaced by the reducer. But apparently you still need it.

Comment: Since you are using a central state management system(redux, in this case), you can skip using state hooks, but then you'd have to replace `useState` variable/function with redux's variable and function.